# Why am I getting "String or Binary Data would be Truncated Error" when there's no INSERT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, truncation

I have this query:

```
USE [SomeDatabase];
GO

DECLARE @percentageValue decimal(15,4) = 1.50; 

SELECT a.ID, a.Amount, a.Status 
FROM [dbo].ATable as a          
INNER JOIN [dbo].BTable as b 
  ON a.LinkToB = b.ID
INNER JOIN [OtherDatabase].[dbo].CTable as value 
  ON value.[Key] = CONCAT(N'APrefixAboutThisLongThatsNecessaryBecauseDontAsk',b.AltID)
WHERE a.Status = N'SomeStatus'
AND a.Amount > (COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), value.Value), 0)*@percentageValue);
GO
```

(Actual column names redacted for confidentiality)

And I'm getting the traditional:
"Msg 8152, Level 16, State 10, Line 3
String or binary data would be truncated."
error. Google tells me that I'm trying to insert something into a column that's too small, which makes sense.

However, *this isn't an INSERT operation* (and this is literally all of the SQL for my query), so I can't for the life of me detect where the truncation is happening or why. I assume this is something that's in the bowels of Transact-SQL, but the weirdest issue is that I'm getting results from the query despite the error.

On request, here's the relevant parts of the table schema.

```
USE [SomeDatabase]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ATable](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Amount] [decimal](15, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [LinkToB] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TableA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
))
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BTable](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [AltID]  [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TableA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
))
GO

USE [OtherDatabase]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CTable](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Key] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL)
CONSTRAINT [PK_TableC] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)
```

Comment: What's the size of `Key` column?

Comment: Could you plz post the schema of **BTable** and **CTable** ??

Comment: Also deworde you have a reference to a table alias of "t", t.Status and t.Amount but t alias is not defined.  NOT apart of the problem but confusing.

Comment: @Dbloch: Whoops, fixed, thanks Mack.

Comment: @KrishnrajRana Not really (see confidentiality), but b.ID and b.AltID are both uniqueidentifiers, and c.Key is a nvarchar(100) [Tried changing it to max as a test, no improvement, and c.Value is a nvarchar(max)

Comment: @deworde Which line is line 14?

Comment: @AndrewMorton The line with the select statement on, I think.

Comment: @deworde That doesn't really isolate the problem, so how about using a dummy value instead of the `CONCAT` and see if the error goes away. If not, do the same for the RHS of the `a.Amount >` line.

Comment: @deworde Can you tweak this fiddle so that it accurately reflects your schema? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aae08/2

Comment: What is @status? where are you setting value for it ?

Comment: @deworde surely you can post the schema of the tables and change the column names to gibberish to avoid breaching any confidentiality. Not that you're going to have a proprietary table schema that people in your industry haven't already considered anyway. Besides, this doesn't seem to be the same code, since `@status` isn't set anywhere, and there is no line 14 (the `SELECT` is on line 6). Can you please update the question to more accurately reflect your actual problem?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Sure, but I have to be careful to ensure that I gibberish them up. The line number's wrong, and status is an nvarchar(max). I'll make the modifications Monday. But the question is really *how can a select statement be causing string truncation at all*?

Comment: I don't know, but I don't feel like making guesses without knowing the schema (which is why I keep asking for it). Computed column maybe? *shrug* Don't know, and don't feel like playing fifty questions in lieu of complete info.

Comment: P.S. To be sure that you can, in fact, get this error from just a `SELECT`, try this: `DECLARE @s1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'abc', @s2 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
SELECT @s1 = REPLICATE(@s1,5000), @s2 = NEWID();
SELECT REPLACE(@s2, @s1, 'foo');` Note that I stuck with data types that you are using, too, so I would again check for computed columns or the parts of the batch that you didn't show us...

Comment: @AaronBertrand I've updated (also posted the answer we discovered). And I wasn't asking for 20 questions, I was genuinely seeking to improve my understanding of how T-Sql worked. Sorry if the question wasn't quite up to spec, I was really struggling and frustrated with the whole thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, this one turns out to be interesting but obvious once you know the secret.

As stated in the comments (and on the schema), value.Value is a nvarchar(max). It's the traditional Key-Value antipattern to store data that you don't want to store somewhere specific. Now, we're running try_convert(nvarchar(max)) on this column, but that's fine, because the

```
 ON Key = N'SomethingSpecific'
```

clause will mean that it only runs try_convert on the Key=N'SomethingSpecific' row, right?

Right?

Nope.

**Depending on the *data in the table*, the execution plan can choose to try_convert every value in the column.** And one of the rows in the nvarchar(max) is beyond the capacity of try_convert's parameter. Hence crashy. This also explains why I get all the results I expect back, it's evaluating those results and then coming to the crash on data rows I expected it to be ignoring.

Even better, unrelated data or structure changes can change the behaviour of the execution plan, so this bug can go "Heisenbug" really easily and vanish given more/less data, minor changes to the structure, and on one debugging pass, I'm pretty sure the *whitespace*.

So what's the simplest solution? Get the config value into a variable seperately to the try_convert, and use that instead.

And to anyone designing a database or writing database code:

- Do NOT manipulate data types inside an SQL where clause
- Do NOT use one column to store wildly different datatypes and write complex conversion routines to handle the issues
- DO use the correct datatype for your data and treat additional tables with the correct datatypes as good
- Remember that SQL functions often do INSERT-like operations under the hood

Comment: @HLGEM In my defence, I inherited one through three. Four's on me though.

Answer (score 0):

for grins give this a try

```
USE [SomeDatabase];
GO

DECLARE @percentageValue decimal(15,4) = 1.50; 
DECLARE @prefix nvarchar(max) =  N'APrefixAboutThisLongThatsNecessaryBecauseDontAsk'; 

SELECT a.ID, a.Amount, a.Status 
FROM [dbo].ATable as a          
INNER JOIN [dbo].BTable as b 
  ON a.LinkToB = b.ID
INNER JOIN [OtherDatabase].[dbo].CTable as value 
  ON value.[Key] = CONCAT(@prefix,b.AltID)
WHERE a.Status = @status
AND a.Amount > (COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), value.Value), 0)*@percentageValue);
GO
```

Comment: Nice idea, but it turns out not to be that.